# Enabling audit logs in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I followed enabling Audit logs for my yb universe and I was able to enable it. However, I was wondering where do the Audit logs get captured at? For e.g, I tried looking for any part of the below logs in tserver or even pgsql logs but didn't find any. Where is the audit logs captured?

```
NOTICE: AUDIT: SESSION,2,1,DDL,CREATE TABLE,TABLE,public.employees,
"create table employees ( empno int, ename text, address text, salary int,
account_number text );",<not logged>
CREATE TABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about YSQL (PostgreSQL based) auditing.
Auditing in YSQL is provided by an extension. This extension is not installed by default, and therefore to be used must first be enabled in YSQL. That is done using the `create extension` command, such as `create extension if not exists pgaudit;`.

This provides the audit functionality, but in order to make YSQL perform the auditing, it must be configured. The pgaudit extension adds some parameters to the database that can be set at database startup, or dynamically by a superuser. These parameters are `pgaudit.{role, log_relation, log_statement_once, log_parameter, log_level, log_catalog, log}`.

As an example: in order to audit all statements, perform: `set pgaudit.log='ALL';`
To start auditing, and then `select 1+1`.

The auditing is performed in the PostgreSQL logfile in the 'log' directory of each tserver and contains the locally audited commands. The base path is set by the tserver flag `--fs-data-dirs`, and the path to the logfile of the server is yb-data/tserver/logs.

As an example, I just tried this:

```bash
./bin/yugabyted destroy
./bin/yugabyted start
./bin/ysqlsh
```

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgaudit;
SET pgaudit.log='ALL';
select 1;
select 'a';
```

Then get the logs:

```bash
./bin/yugabyted collect_logs
```

Go into the zip file, and check the .postgresql logs, you should see something like:

```
I0603 10:36:36.737246 17050 pg_client.cc:130] S 1: Session id acquired
2022-06-03 10:37:04.029 UTC [17050] LOG:  AUDIT: SESSION,1,1,MISC,SET,,,SET pgaudit.log='ALL';,<not logged>
2022-06-03 10:37:25.901 UTC [17050] LOG:  AUDIT: SESSION,2,1,READ,SELECT,,,select 1;,<not logged>
2022-06-03 10:37:33.204 UTC [17050] LOG:  AUDIT: SESSION,3,1,READ,SELECT,,,select 'a';,<not logged>
```